# Passing userDataDir to Puppeteer does not access the correct saved logins as regular Chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, browser, automation, puppeteer

I want to use Puppeteer (v20.8.0) to control the same profile/session as my regular Chrome browser. Specifically, I would like the websites I have logged in to to stay logged in when opening a new Puppeteer instance.

Passing `userDataDir` to Puppeteer does not work as expected.

I am able to open a Puppeteer Chrome instance and the instance definitely has the bookmarks and profile picture and even the same tabs as a non-Puppeteer-spawned Chrome. The Puppeteer-spawned Chrome instance also has the "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" message.

However, on the Puppeteer-spawned Chrome, I am not logged in any websites that I am normally on the non-Puppeteer-spawned Chrome browser. So it's like the cookies, storage, or whatever is not working properly or not being used by Puppeteer or something.

```
const os = require('os');
const username = os.userInfo().username;
const workingExePath = '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome';
const workingDataBaseDir = `/Users/${username}/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome`

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  executablePath: workingExePath, // supply the user-specific path here
  defaultViewport: {
    width: 1280,
    height: 720
  },
  userDataDir: workingDataBaseDir, // supply the user-specific path here

  args: [
    '--mute-audio', // this mutes the entire browser, not just one tab
    '--profile-directory=Default',
  ]
});

const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox');
```

[image]

To see if I could have any more luck, I manually copied the `userDataDir` to `/Users/${username}/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome_` (just has an underscore at the end) and tried using this new folder with Puppeteer but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- For me this code worked better when I pointed the profile location to a local folder from where I ran it (`./`) The profile and cookies were working, whereas in the old location it was very finicky, sometimes throwing "Failed to launch the browser process" error, sometimes not picking up the cookies properly.
- You can see the real location that ends up being in effect by typing `chrome://version/` in the browser bar, sometimes it's not what i thought it would be.
- Gmail itself may have additional puppeteer detection measures, even if your profile works well and retains the cookies. Might need Chromium or a different browser carefully tuned to look real.
- Another thing you can try (depends on your desired setup) is connecting to a live browser instance that has profile already configured and running like this:

```js
    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
      browserURL: 'http://localhost:9222'
    })
```